# How to disable discrete Nvidia GPU in Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm new to Linux world. I have an old laptop with Intel HD 3000 and GT 630M gpu. But there is problem with GT 630M. The Ubuntu freezes when I want to open Mozilla or something. It also freezes when I'm on windows. So i know that there is problem with the GT 630M. I would just want to know how to disable it in Ubuntu. p.s GPU cannot be disable in Bios